# Filtering object model django with list of values

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am building a django project and I have a list of ids [23,44,12,67] and I have a model named testmodel

```
 tests = testmodel.objects.all()
```

But I want to remove/filter(I don't want to remove from database, just filter) the objects which has the ids in my list. Any help how I can achieve this in a simple way using django ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `.exclude()` ORM method:

```
testmodel.objects.exclude(id__in=[23,44,12,67])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tests = testmodel.objects.exclude(id__in=[23, 44, 12, 67])
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
test = testmodel.objects.exclude(pk__in=[23,44,12,67])
```

You can find more information [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut)